# Inserting a value to a Foreign key using java and database

Tags: java, mysql, database

i need some solution from my foreign key in inserting a FK ID the problem is when i insert the ID, and the Payment it will insert first Customer_ID and the second is default to null value and on next column it will set to the inserted and the other one is null here's my code

```
pStmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Audittrail_tbl (Customer_ID) values ((Select Name_ID from Customer_tbl where FName ='"+txtFName.getText()+"' and LName = '"+txtLName.getText()+"'))");
    pStmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Audittrail_tbl (Payment) values ('"+txtPayment.getText()+"')");
    pStmt2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: That code inserts two rows: First row has Payment=null, second row has Customer_ID=null.

Comment: yes sir, i wanted it to execute in the same row

Comment: You should not use `PrepreparedStatement` in the way that you have used.

Comment: i tried it to be pStmt2.setString(1,"blabla") and (2,"blabla"); but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
String sql = "insert into Audittrail_tbl (Customer_ID, Payment)" +
            " select Name_ID, ?" +
              " from Customer_tbl" +
             " where FName = ?" +
               " and LName = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, txtPayment.getText());
    stmt.setString(2, txtFName.getText());
    stmt.setString(3, txtLName.getText());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Or better yet, if `Payment` is an amount column:

```
// Using BigDecimal
stmt.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(txtPayment.getText()));

// Using Double
stmt.setDouble(1, Double.parseDouble(txtPayment.getText()));
```

Since that will parse the text to number in Java code, where you can better handle parse errors.

**Note:** Using insert-from-select, instead of insert-values with a subquery, will allow you to select multiple columns from `Customer_tbl` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing two inserts, which creates two records. if you want to update the record created by the first query, you need to `UPDATE` for the second query instead.

And why use two queries? Why not

```
pStmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("
    insert into Audittrail_tbl (Customer_ID, Payment)
    values (
        (Select Name_ID from Customer_tbl where FName ='"+txtFName.getText()+"' and LName = '"+txtLName.getText()+"'),
        '"+txtPayment.getText()+"')");)");
```

Of course, that won't work as-is (I'm too lazy to check quote/bracket matching), but should give you the general idea.